# How to remove little camera movements

Tags: video, software-recommendation, stabilisation

I want to remove little camera movements from a video. Is this possible?
I tried virtualdub with deshaker plugin, but it only works for shaking.

- Shooting position: bridge
- Weather: strong wind

Example shot on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w49zCnAzZ4k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe premiere and After effects have a stabilizer plugin with a "no motion" setting that does what you want. These are commercial applications.

The free Da vinci resolve lite also has a "stabilize option" (but I have never tried it personally)

Comment: If you have After Effects or Mocha you could track those building and use the track to stabilize the video. By manually tracking the motion you decide, what to eliminate and don't leave it as guesswork to the computer. If done right, this would give the best result and in your case wouldn't take long.

Comment: Da Vinci Resolve 11 Lite is free and awesome. Thx @kazanaki !

Answer (score 3):

FFMpeg's [`vid.stab` filter](http://public.hronopik.de/vid.stab/) is configurable.  Crank up the time-scale and even slow global motion should get stabilized.

You have to run it as a 2-pass process: detect, and then stabilize.  If you're going to do more with the video later, after stabilizing, output to a lossless format and then point your other tools at that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to try is [Prodad Mercalli](http://vegasaur.com/Mercalli) - a standalone application with some very cool features, such as CMOS correction. Contains many built-in presets for action cameras. Not cheap, though.